# How to execute .css files in Qt?

Tags: qt

I am having a .css file (with some button images and background image) instead of using style sheet and had added it to my project.

I don't know how to link the .css file with my button image and background.

If anyone knows how to add it please get me some sample or examples for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just read the file in your application and apply it to the whole application (or anything else):

```
void main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    QApplication app( argc, argv );

    QFile styleSheetFile( ":/stylesheet.css" );  // assuming stylesheet is part of the resources
    styleSheetFile.open( QFile::ReadOnly );
    QString styleSheet = styleSheetFile.readAll();

    app->setStyleSheet( styleSheet );
}
```